# Objective-c core graphics draw rotated image not working

Tags: objective-c, quartz-2d, cg

i am trying to draw rotated image with following code

```
CGLayerRef layer=CGLayerCreateWithContext(context,CGSizeMake(brush.size.width*2,brush.size.height*2), NULL);
CGContextRef tmp=CGLayerGetContext(layer);
CGContextDrawImage(tmp,CGRectMake(brush.size.width/2, brush.size.height/2, brush.size.width, brush.size.height), brush.CGImage);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(tmp, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetBlendMode(tmp, kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextFillRect(tmp, CGRectMake(0, 0, 2*brush.size.width, 2*brush.size.height));
CGContextSetBlendMode(tmp, kCGBlendModeNormal);
CGContextTranslateCTM(tmp, -brush.size.width/2, -brush.size.height/2);
CGContextRotateCTM(tmp, angle);
CGContextTranslateCTM(tmp, brush.size.width/2, brush.size.height/2);
CGContextDrawImage(tmp,CGRectMake(brush.size.width/2, brush.size.height/2, brush.size.width, brush.size.height), brush.CGImage);
```

I want to place image at the center of layer (image is square)

Comment: Is the image simply not getting drawn at all, or is it getting drawn incorrectly?

Comment: @TannerSilva drawn incorrectly,it seems that its outside of the layer

Answer (score 0):

try the rotation then the translation